# .editorconfig folder-specific configuration

Tags: laravel, editorconfig

I have a Laravel 5.8 project and my `.editorconfig` setup is based on PHP coding (with 4 spaces) and some other considerations. What I want to know if there is a way to set up a folder-specific configuration for my `resources/js` in order to adapt different coding rules (like 2 spaces).

Also, is there a way to setup eslint in this project to also lint my js code without any trouble?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, you can specify a path within the section name's square brackets:

```
# Rules specified in this section matching all files
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

[*.php]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

# Rules in here only match .js files inside your resources/js folder.
[resources/js/**.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Read more on the main page of [editorconfig.com](https://editorconfig.org/).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot Dan